# WordPress Nginx rewrite rules

Tags: wordpress, nginx

I change my permanent link to  /%postname%.html and add the rules suggested by Nginx(https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/recipes/wordpress/) as follows:

```
location / {
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}

# Add trailing slash to */wp-admin requests.
rewrite /wp-admin$ $scheme://$host$uri/ permanent;
```

It works quite well when I visit my blog like https://www.vpsgo.com/cloudcone-cheap-plans.html.

However,

when I visit a random link like https://www.vpsgo.com/random111, it returns me the homepage of my website with the http status code 200 rather than 404 page.

Plus,

when I visit a search page like https://www.vpsgo.com/?s=random111, it works well again and return the 404 page with 404 http code.

How to solve such problems?

Answer (score 0):

you can try

try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args; #Mantain the appended query string intact

depend how you configure your method like fastcgi sock or ip:port and includes or not snipets

for 4xx status codes are you redirecting those status codes to your homepage?